# Creating a XPathNavigator or XPathNodeIterator on plain objects?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpathnavigator

I need to feed a large object array (plain CLR objects with public properties) into an XSL transform and I wish not to serialize this object array to XML to get an `XPathNavigator` first.

I'm trying to inject a `XPathNodeIterator` with an extension object, but I still don't know how to create an navigator or iterator over these objects without having to serialize them first, which would seem a little wasteful.

Are there any `XPathNavigator` implementations for plain objects?

Comment: It is not possible. XSLT works with XML, so you must pass XML into transformer.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950764.aspx, I have not checked whether the source code for the article is still available but I think it talks about what you are looking for.